# How to split the world in four quadrants as ee.Image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I creating a test suit for a Python lib and I need to create test datasets to play with. I would like to create an `ee.Image` with 4 integer values:

- 1 north-West quadrant
- 2 north-east
- 3 south-West
- 4 south-east

something that should look like this:
[image]

Is there an easy way to do such a thing in EarthEngine?

Comment: You can use the code editor to draw each polygon (or define them using their coordinates), then create an ee.Image(value) and clip it to each of the four geometries

Comment: Put all four images in an imageCollection then join them using max() function or whichever (shouldn't matter)

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a8e3788c96b3f393a76fe1a0fbf8c47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing here the solution proposed by @DanielWiell in his script: [code.earthengine.google.com/3a8e3788c96b3f393a76fe1a0fbf8c47](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a8e3788c96b3f393a76fe1a0fbf8c47)

first create 2 images that are representing longitude and latitude

```js
var lon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('longitude')
var lat = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude')
```

then edit a constant image using conditional `where`:

```js
var image = ee.Image(1)
  .where(lon.gt(0).and(lat.gt(0)), 2)
  .where(lon.lte(0).and(lat.lte(0)), 3)
  .where(lon.gt(0).and(lat.lte(0)), 4)
```

finally you can clip it to a geometry to display it:

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0])
  .buffer(1e6)
  .bounds()

Map.centerObject(geometry)
Map.addLayer(image.clip(geometry))
```